# RESTful API :: Visibility of resource with different user permissions

Tags: rest, permissions, api-design

I am working in a restful api to use in mobile and website but I can not find documentation to understand the right way to use resources with different user permission

E.g.: I have the the endpoints

```
[GET] /users (scope: admin)
[GET] /users/:id (scope: admin/user)

{
    id: 1,
    username: "test",
    email: "test@mail.com"
}
```

The first endpoint is not a problem, only admins can see the list of users.
But the second is the one I want to use to render the profile page and it needs to be available to all the users. Also it will be used for admin users for moderation.

The email is useful for admin users but it should not be included in the json for normal users.
Should I add the logic on the same endpoint or create a new one like /profile ?

```
[GET] /users (scope: admin)
[GET] /users/:id (scope: admin)
[GET] /profile/:id (scope: user)
```

In other hand, I am also thinking about what is the best way to display / hide resources depending of the status.
Lets say I have books with status like  "pending of approval", "available", "removed".

```
[GET] /books/1

{
    id: 1,
    content: "...",
    status: "removed"
}
```

If I am an admin user, I need to see all the posts but If I am common user I should only have access to the ones in "available"
Should I use the same endpoint and add the logic inside depending of the scope? or should I create a new one like /public/books ?
If I use the same one, should I return 404 if the book is pending of approval only for common usrees?

Both problems are similar in some point because both are related to the user permissions.

If would be great if you can help me with it. The examples I found are very simples.

Thanks!!